# Can someone help me edit this Drupal module code to calculate price of all product options instead of just the first option?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using a Drupal 7 module that can add or subtract a selected option price from a product line item price.

The Drupal module is called 'Commerce Product Extra Charge' https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/gbyteco/2565693

It is a sandbox module which is why I am asking here.

The module is working perfectly when selecting only one option. But if you allow selecting multiple options, it only adds the price of the first selected option to the line item total.

I would like to edit this module to update the price with the combined total of all selected options.

**Currently how it works**

- Product price £5
- Option 1 +£10
- Option 2 +£10
- Option 3 +£10

I select all options.

Cart total is £15. (Product price plus option 1 price)

**How I would like it to work**

- Product price £5
- Option 1 +£10
- Option 2 +£10
- Option 3 +£10

I select all options.

Cart total is £35. (Product price plus option1, option2, and option 3 price)

I really hope someone can help me.

Many thanks

Module Code

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Main module file implementing drupal (commerce) hooks.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter
 */
function commerce_option_extra_charge_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if(!isset($form_state['commerce_option']))
    return;
  foreach(element_children($form_state['commerce_option']) as $option_field_name) {
    foreach(element_children($form[$option_field_name]) as $option_index) {
      foreach(element_children($form[$option_field_name][$option_index]) as $taxonomy_field_name) {
        $lang = $form[$option_field_name][$option_index][$taxonomy_field_name]['#language'];
        if (isset($form[$option_field_name][$option_index][$taxonomy_field_name][$lang]['#options'])) {
          foreach($form[$option_field_name][$option_index][$taxonomy_field_name][$lang]['#options'] as $tid => &$name) {
            $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
            if ($term !== FALSE) {
              foreach($term as $term_key => $term_element) {
                if (field_info_field($term_key)['type'] == 'commerce_price' && isset($term_element[key($term_element)][0]['amount'])) {
                  $currency = commerce_currency_load($term_element[key($term_element)][0]['currency_code']);
                  $extra_charge = number_format((float)$term_element[key($term_element)][0]['amount']/100, /*$currency['decimals']*/2, $currency['decimal_separator'], '');
                  $name .= ' (' . ($extra_charge >= 0 ? '+' : '') . $extra_charge . ' ' . $currency['symbol'] . ')';
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh
 */
function commerce_option_extra_charge_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh($line_item, $order_wrapper) {
  foreach($line_item as $key => $element) {
    if (!commerce_option_set_load_by_name($key))
      continue;
    $chosen_option = unserialize($line_item->$key);
    $field_name = key($chosen_option);
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($chosen_option[$field_name][key($chosen_option[$field_name])][0]['tid']);
    foreach($term as $term_key => $term_element) {
      if (field_info_field($term_key)['type'] == 'commerce_price' && isset($term_element[key($term_element)][0]['amount'])) {
        $extra_charge = (float)$term_element[key($term_element)][0]['amount'];
        $line_item->commerce_unit_price[key($term_element)]['0']['amount'] = (float)$line_item->commerce_unit_price[key($term_element)]['0']['amount'] + $extra_charge;
      }
    }
  }
  $lang = key($line_item->commerce_unit_price);
  if ($line_item->commerce_unit_price[$lang]['0']['amount'] < 0) {
    $line_item->commerce_unit_price[$lang]['0']['amount'] = 0;
    watchdog('commerce_option_extra_charge', t('The price calculation in commerce_option_extra_charge_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh() came out negative. Therefore the final price was set to 0.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: A few things that just killed it. It's not something I am able to fix. I just discovered fiverr though so I am gonna get it fixed without all the messing about.